# How do I use Typescript to compile .NET assemblies for use with Unity3d?

Tags: javascript, .net, typescript, unity-game-engine

Unity3d noob looking to use Typescript for Unity3d scripting instead of C# or UnityScript (Unity3d's JavaScript-like-but-not-really-JavaScript language).

Theory is that if I can compile Typescript to .NET assemblies that can run within Unity3d (ie, Mono), I'm golden.

Before you suggest existing JavaScript-.NET interop solutions like Jist or JavaScript.NET, I'm thinking that they'll fall short because Unity3d (and, by extension, .NET) depends on types, and, if I'm not mistaken, *transpiling* Typescript to JavaScript then using Jist/JavaScript.NET loses type information.  A Typescript .NET *compiler* would retain type information.

Bonus points for reference to tool that allows .NET assemblies (like Unity3d's) to be used from Typescript code.

Comment: If you are serious about using Unity you have to learn C#. I have see others using F# or some other language in Unity but there is always a problem. C# is not hard to learn.

Comment: @Programmer, I get it.  It's just that there's a huge world outside of C# out there.  Lots of great, reusable code.  FWIW, I've used C# plenty in my career...

Comment: I know there is a a huge world outside of C#. I made that comment because many people don't want to let go of their language they already know and want to use them with Unity instead of C#.

Comment: As for re-usable code, Typescript  is not especially in Unity. If you want your code to be re-usable, port them to C or C++. You can use these in Unity with a simple wrapper. If you already have large code written in Typescript, you should have to spend some time and port them to C#.

Comment: @Matthew Adams Did you try it with ClearScript and did it work? If it worked, were there any things to consider?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/im-a-noob-why-not-typescript.488535/) you said that you can write C#. You can look at Microsoft.ClearScript. It allows you to embed scripting languages in .NET programs. It has built in support for [V8](https://v8.dev). If you can figure out how to implement it in Unity (by writing a little bit of C#), then you can use JavaScript. And you could (although not ideal) compile TS code to JS, then run it directly in your Unity game. It would be slow on a large scale because it's interpreted, but it's possible. Using C# code you can expose `UnityEngine` API to JS. It's not the best solution (if you can even call it a solution), but it works (or at least should work). I know I'm like 4 years late but it's still useful for anyone else who sees it. I'd love to hear if you found any solution since you asked this.

Edit: A more performance-friendly way would be to use [AssemblyScript](https://assemblyscript.org), a TypeScript-like language that compiles to WASM. You could then use something like [wasmtime-dotnet](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime-dotnet) to execute the WebAssembly. This is a very similar approach to the one above, but in my opinion is cleaner than transpiling TypeScript to JavaScript, then executing it in V8. And, of course, it should be much more efficient, and potentially be harder for people to get the source of your game.

Comment: @Brendon Do you know if already some tried to use ClearScript with Unity or where did you read that this is possible?

Comment: ClearScript is a Nuget package for C#. I'm not entirely sure if you can add Nuget packages to Unity projects or not. If not, you could build a DLL from source and import it into Unity. You would have to use C# to expose the Unity APIs to JS either way.

Comment: I forgot that I commented this here. So I tried ClearScript out and it worked for Unity on Windows. What I also tried (supported by ClearScript) is getting it to run on a HoloLens (UWP & ARM64), but this is not possible right now.

Comment: @Perazim, I don't see .NET libraries working in Unity for Linux unless they start using .NET 5/6, where building for Linux is supported. Currently, Unity uses IL2CPP to convert the C# to C++ code and then compile to Linux binaries. But, you could try adding the `Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.linux-x64` package.

Answer (score 1):

I think Unity has made a wrong strategic desicion not adopting typescript. Army or Frontend/full stack nodejs devs is way larger, and the language itself is potent and mature. This would make all gaming  industry more open, resulting a real boom

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question, you can't use typescript in unity3d. 
Unity3d not support this.

Comment: Theoretically false.  I can use .NET assemblies in Unity3d:  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html.  Given that, if I can compile Typescript to a .NET DLL, then I'm golden.

Comment: if you compile typescript to a .NET dll your using .NET

Comment: no, only .NET, same that if you wrap a c++ code in your .NET dll your not using c++ in unity3d, your using .Net to bypass or translate but unity3d not support directly.